# How to pre populate dropdown based on another dropdown in Ruby on Rhodes application with Ajax and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, rhodes

I want to pre-populate select menu dropdown for state and city when Country is selected in Ruby on Rhodes app. Can any one help me how to do it?